# How to change current template/route by an external script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

In my ember.js-app, Ive got one template which includes a javascript-jQuery-script. Within this script I want to call ember to read out some variables, safe them, and then change the template

Like so

```
finishedGame = function() {
  // ember create model-entry by using "this.points"
  // ember change the template to "game/credits"
};
```

How can I use ember to hook into an independent-running script and start functionality like switching templates etc. or ist it possible to access the controller functions from elsewhere than the ember-scripts itselv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very bad approach would be to use a global variable to do this and then observe it from within Ember as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14290316/observe-non-ember-globals), then you can trigger whatever action you require, but this is definitely **not recommended**.

As [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16879306/2533680) states, if you find yourself thinking a global variable is the best solution it's a sign that something should be refactored.

So in this case I would go with calling the `finishedGame()` function from within an Ember scope, like the controller (probably with Ember.$ if it is jQuery) and have this function return the values you want to save, then issue a call to a `transitionToRoute` method ([take a look at this documentation](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Controller.html#method_transitionToRoute)).